# Is it possible to change the primary cartridge in an OpenShift application?

Tags: openshift

I've created Tomcat7 application on openshift but now I want to change it to JBoss Application Server 7. Is it possible without recreating app (delete T7 and then create JB AS 7)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately no, you will have to delete your gear and redeploy with a JBoss Application Server cartridge. However the war files shouldn't need to be altered.

Answer (score 3):

It should be noted that you can archive the app's deployments and deploy the resulting artifact to another application.  So, for your use case, you would:

1. Create an archive of your current application using `rhc snapshot save --deployment` (passing `-a <app name>` if not in that application's git repo directory).
2. Create a new application of the desired type.
3. Deploy the archive created in step 1 to the new application using `rhc deploy --ref <path to archive>` (passing `-a <app name>` if not in that application's git repo direcory).

You could use this approach to test your app on another flavor of JBoss.